Traefik 3: Getting 404 response despite seemingly correct router setup
I'm really scratching my head on this one, hoping someone could provide a friendly pointer to the thing I'm obviously missing.
some context: I'm currently running Traefik 2 on my home server to route requests to various services hosted in independent docker compose stacks... this is based on request hostname... works like a charm... for reasons, I need to start hosting some services directly on the web, so I got a new, more powerful vps (my old one basically just does request proxying through a tunnel to my home server) where I'll replicate the docker setup but front it directly with Traefik. However, I wanted to use this opportunity to move to Traefik 3 and streamline the setup such that I don't need a gazillion container labels any more.
I've tried doing a very minimal setup to get going with a new instance of authelia on a subdomain of mine and I cannot, for the life of me, get my requests routed to it. The service and route get created as expected (verified through logs and dashboard - which btw I also can't get a working route to but could only access through exposing the insecure port and forwarding that via ssh), the Traefik container can get to the detected service address, but no bueno. screenshots show a relevant access log snippet as well as the dashboard page of that router.
Here's a dashboard screenshot of the router:

Here's a relevant access log snippet:
{
    "ClientAddr": "1.2.3.4:33198",
    "ClientHost": "1.2.3.4",
    "ClientPort": "33198",
    "ClientUsername": "-",
    "DownstreamContentSize": 19,
    "DownstreamStatus": 404,
    "Duration": 28332,
    "GzipRatio": 0,
    "OriginContentSize": 0,
    "OriginDuration": 0,
    "OriginStatus": 0,
    "Overhead": 28332,
    "RequestAddr": "login.example.com",
    "RequestContentSize": 0,
    "RequestCount": 197,
    "RequestHost": "login.example.com",
    "RequestMethod": "GET",
    "RequestPath": "/",
    "RequestPort": "-",
    "RequestProtocol": "HTTP/2.0",
    "RequestScheme": "https",
    "RetryAttempts": 0,
    "StartLocal": "2024-09-02T21:08:50.985375098Z",
    "StartUTC": "2024-09-02T21:08:50.985375098Z",
    "TLSCipher": "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
    "TLSVersion": "1.3",
    "entryPointName": "https",
    "level": "info",
    "msg": "",
    "time": "2024-09-02T21:08:50Z"
}

Here's my static config
# traefik.yaml
api:
  dashboard: true
  insecure: true

log:
  level: TRACE

accessLog:
  addInternals: true
  format: json

providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    network: traefik
    constraints: 'LabelRegex(`publicName`, `.+`)'
    defaultRule: 'Host(`{{ index .Labels "publicName" }}`)'
    watch: true

  file:
    directory: /etc/traefik/dynamic
    watch: true

entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ':80'
    http:
      redirections:
        entryPoint:
          to: https
          scheme: https

  https:
    address: ':443'
    http3: {}

http:
  routers:
    dashboard:
      rule: Host(`traefik.example.com`) && (PathPrefix(`/api`) || PathPrefix(`/dashboard`))
      service: api@internal

And here's the relevant log lines from the Docker provider setting up the authelia router:
traefik_1  | 2024-09-03T06:48:26Z DBG github.com/traefik/traefik/v3/pkg/server/configurationwatcher.go:227 > Configuration received config={"http":{"routers":{"authelia-authelia":{"rule":"Host(`login.beikeil.de`)","service":"authelia-authelia"}},"services":{"authelia-authelia":{"loadBalancer":{"passHostHeader":true,"responseForwarding":{"flushInterval":"100ms"},"servers":[{"url":"http://172.24.0.3:9091"}]}}}},"tcp":{},"tls":{},"udp":{}} providerName=docker
traefik_1  | 2024-09-03T06:48:26Z DBG github.com/traefik/traefik/v3/pkg/server/aggregator.go:51 > No entryPoint defined for this router, using the default one(s) instead entryPointName=["http","https"] routerName=authelia-authelia
traefik_1  | 2024-09-03T06:48:26Z DBG github.com/traefik/traefik/v3/pkg/server/service/service.go:267 > Creating load-balancer entryPointName=http routerName=authelia-authelia@docker serviceName=authelia-authelia@docker
traefik_1  | 2024-09-03T06:48:26Z DBG github.com/traefik/traefik/v3/pkg/server/service/service.go:309 > Creating server entryPointName=http routerName=authelia-authelia@docker serverName=d0f918a881967889 serviceName=authelia-authelia@docker target=http://172.24.0.3:9091

I'm at a complete loss as to what I'm missing and hope someone can help me out a bit.
And just because I've got this feedback multiple times from other places already and it's becoming pretty frustrating: No, the router is not missing entry points - as can clearly be seen on the screenshot as well as clearly stated by the log message that starts with "No entryPoint defined for this router" - a surprising number of people seem to be unable to read past that and digest the entire log message before drawing conclusions .
Thanks in advance!
Cheers

This was the answer: https://serverfault.com/a/1106854/52395
While the router gets created dynamically as expected, it does so without TLS config and the default TLS config does not automatically apply... after explicitly adding an empty TLS config via a container label, things started working
